# Adding pages to ViewPager beyond its setOffScreenPageLimit value

Tags: android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I'm using a `ViewPager` in my Android app. The app allows the user to add and remove pages, each time adding a `ListFragment` to the new page with a page addition. My adapter is a `FragmentPagerAdapter`. This all works great until I add one page more than the value I specify in setOffScreenPageLimit + 1. For example, I define:

```
mPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

I can add up to 6 (5 off-screen pages + 1 visible page) pages with no issue. When I add the seventh page, the app crashes when trying to call `getActivity()` in my `ListFragment` code because there `Activity = null`. I should also mention that the `getActivity()` call is in the `onPostExecute` method of an AsyncTask (still trying to figure out if something is out of sync...).

What am I missing here...?